# How can I filter data frame in r?

Tags: r, filter, group-by

I have a data frame like the following:

```
id    areaID    time
325   10152    12:55
325   10221    11:57
325   10152    10:53
325   10152    08:35
525   10152    10:15
525   10221    16:45
725   10152    11:55
825   10152    12:06
925   10221    18:09
925   10221    19:45
935   10152    08:05
935   10221    10:05
```

I want to keep only those groups where both areaID 10152 and 10221 are available. Therefore, it should be something like this:

- id    areaID    time
- 325    10152     12:55
- 325    10221    11:57
- 325    10152    10:53
- 325    10152    08:35
- 525    10152    10:15
- 525    10221    16:45
- 935    10152    08:05
- 935    10221    10:05

Can anyone help me out? TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is stored as `d`, then a grouped filter with `dplyr` should do it.

```r
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(10152 %in% areaID & 10221 %in% areaID)

#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id areaID   time
#>   <int>  <int> <fctr>
#> 1   325  10152  12:55
#> 2   325  10221  11:57
#> 3   325  10152  10:53
#> 4   325  10152  08:35
#> 5   525  10152  10:15
#> 6   525  10221  16:45
#> 7   935  10152  08:05
#> 8   935  10221  10:05
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. But for some reason it's not filtering my data. There is no error, not even any warning.

Comment: Is your data named `d`?

Comment: nope. 
library(dplyr)
Keep_files %>% 
   group_by(deviceid) %>% filter(10152 %in% areaId & 10221 %in% areaId)
This is what I am giving input.

Comment: What is the output? Are `areaId` and `deviceid` the column names (correctly) in your data?

Comment: Yes. 
The output is as same as the previous data set. There are 86000 rows before filtering and after filtering it remains same. And All group remains same as before. areaId and deviceid both are <int>. :(

Comment: I think you want `all(c(10152,10221) %in% areaID)` as a generic solution. This will be difficult to extend to many values if you have to repeat `100 %in% areaID & 200 %in% areaID & 300 %in% areaID ...` many times.

Comment: created a dummy data set and works fine with it, but not the original data set.

Comment: @Pasha are you sure your `areaId` are numeric in the original?

Comment: @thelatemail yes, that's more succinct. I was being a little more verbose for the simple example.

Comment: @jonathan, the class is integer in the original.